# Store area unit conversion in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have land buy/sell related website. So I want to store land area units in India and their conversion in other in units in mysql table. When user from specific area see properties list on website and if he selects acre in dropdown list then he can see the every property area in the acre though the property was listed in another unit.
So How Do I do this??

Comment: Please provide some code snippets.

Comment: I haven't done anything. I just want to know logic behind this.

Comment: Do you have knowledge of Jquery and Ajax?

Comment: How you are showing property area?

Answer (score 1):

A simple two table can do this .. if you like..

```
Table 1:Units[id,UnitName]
Table 2:ConversionUnit[conversionId,fromUnitId,toUnitId,offset]
```

such as

```
table 1: [1,Centimetre],[2,Mitre],[3,kilometre]
table 2: [1,1,2,100],[1,3,1,0.000001]
```

First entry in the table to for converting CM to M and second row is to convert from KM to CM.

Hope it helps..